# Can't read text file while it is being produced by running C-program

Tags: command-line

I have a little c-program, d, that takes a long time and produces a lot of text output.
When I run the the program with ./d I can see the output being scrolled on the screen
but if I do
./d > d10.txt
I can't read d10.txt with cat d10.txt until the program has finished.
Why is this so and what can I do to monitor the output while the program is running?
Thanks for any tip
H

Comment: Perhaps your program buffers its output when writing to a file not a terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the output because you are redirecting it into the file.

To both see the output and store it in a file, use the `tee` program:

```bsh
./d | tee d10.txt
```

You could also do this, but it's much more work:

```bsh
> d10.txt
tail -f d10.txt &
./d >> d10.txt
kill %1
```

Comment: Thanks, it should but it doesn't seem to work.
I changed my program by adding a fprintf:
printf("%d %.3f \n",t,voltage);
fprintf(stderr,"E %d %.3f \n",t,voltage);
and ./d | tee d15.txt results in:
E 0 0.004 
E 1 0.001 
E 2 0.000 
E 3 -0.001 
E 4 -0.001 
...

Comment: Please find below a little program that tee doesn't behave as I would expect.
./notee | tee /dev/null
produces:
E 4 
E 3 
E 2 
E 1 
E 0 
finito 
4 
3 
2 
1 
0 


#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int t=5;
while(t--){
printf("%d \n",t);
fprintf(stderr,"E %d \n",t);
}
  fprintf(stderr,"finito \n");
  return 0;
}

Comment: The pipe only connects a program's *stdout* to the stdin of the next program. What do you expect to happen to stderr?

Comment: I put in  fprintf(stderr,"E %d \n",t); to visualise what the program was doing and it clearly shows that the screen isn't updated before the program has terminated.
If I put in a fflush(stdout); after the printf statement the tee behaviour is as I would expect.
I had thought that the newline at the end of the printf statement should take care of flushing the terminal buffer.

#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int t=20;
while(t--){
printf("%d \n",t);
fprintf(stderr,"E %d \n",t);
fflush(stdout);
}
  fprintf(stderr,"finito \n");
  return 0;
}